# how to locate class name , automation id in winnappdriver for desktop application automation

Tags: desktop-application

getting error : No such element exception

cannot resolve this issue

Entered classname,ID's available in windows kits package> inspect.exe

but issue didn't resolve

Answer (score 0):

To locate a class name or automation ID in WinAppDriver for desktop application automation, you can use the **GetClassName** and **GetAutomationId** methods respectively. These methods can be used on a **WindowsElement** object to retrieve the class name or automation ID for that element.

As an example

```
// First, get a reference to the element you want to inspect
WindowsElement element = driver.FindElementByClassName("my-element-class");

// Now you can use the GetClassName and GetAutomationId methods to retrieve the class name and automation ID for that element
string className = element.GetClassName();
string automationId = element.GetAutomationId();

// You can now use the class name and automation ID in your automation scripts
```

It's important to note that these methods will only work if the element you are trying to inspect has a class name or automation ID set. Elements that do not have these attributes set will return an empty string when these methods are called.